# ResizeMode property of WPF window cause position difference at Windows 7 vs. XP

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-xp, window, position

I define two windows in the new WPF Application project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindowSizeLocationDifferenceXP7.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Left="100" Top="100" Height="200" Width="200"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"/>

<Window x:Class="WpfWindowSizeLocationDifferenceXP7.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2"
    Left="300" Top="100" Height="200" Width="200"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"/>
```

As you can see, the windows are standing side-by-side and the only difference is in ResizeMode property value. Second window means to be non-resizeable. The result in Windows XP vs. result in Windows 7 is dramatic different.

Sorry. As a new user I can't post images, so here are plain links to them.

Windows XP (expected result): http://s9.postimage.org/qrojbckil/Wpf_Window_Size_Location_XP.jpg

Windows 7 (unexpected result): http://s16.postimage.org/6nmyc6b79/Wpf_Window_Size_Location_7.png

What is the cause of the difference? How-to handle it, so it become possible to rely on the location and size properties of WPF window?

Comment: I come to conclusion that the cause of the effect is DWM feature of extending frame. Even WinAPI GetWindowRect function be at fault. Need to explore the problem deeper. May be WPF Shell Integration Library already has the workaround ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think Windows applies a different WindowStyle for resizable and non-resizable windows. Try setting the WindowStyle property on your windows explicitly - hopefully that should make them the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx